# What could cause a JS-animated SVG to load on desktop but not on mobile?

Tags: javascript, xml, svg, xhtml, svgator

I designed a vector [loader animation](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/WNZYYPp) composed of 3 separate SVG elements using SVGator's GUI. I exported each as SVG+Javascript, and chose to separate the elements because each uses a different loading/playing function.

When I copied the code into CodePen and my website,  all 3 elements loaded perfectly on desktop. But when testing on mobile (iOS15 Chrome & Safari), the #battery and #cells elements load perfectly, but the #rings element fails to load no matter what.

I've even tried uploading the #rings file to my CMS to use as an html object's data source, but the same thing happened: worked on desktop, failed on mobile. Also occurs when you go to [the file](https://www.charliemoody.com/s/rings.svg) on my domain.

Code for the #rings SVG is pasted below, but more easily readable on the [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/moodyeffects/pen/WNZYYPp) (also linked above).

```
<svg id="rings" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision"><defs><filter id="rings-outerring-filter" x="-400%" width="600%" y="-400%" height="600%"><feGaussianBlur id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-blur" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="25,25"/><feOffset id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-offset" dx="0" dy="0" result="tmp"/><feFlood id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-flood" flood-color="rgba(0,25,249,0.93)"/><feComposite id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-composite" operator="in" in2="tmp"/><feMerge id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-merge"><feMergeNode id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-merge-node-1"/><feMergeNode id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-merge-node-2" in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge><feGaussianBlur id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-blur" in="result" stdDeviation="0,0"/><feOffset id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-offset" dx="0" dy="0" result="tmp"/><feFlood id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-flood" flood-color="#0019f9"/><feComposite id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-composite" operator="in" in2="tmp"/><feMerge id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge" result="result"><feMergeNode id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge-node-1"/><feMergeNode id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge-node-2" in="result"/></feMerge></filter><radialGradient id="rings-outerring-stroke" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="translate(0.5 0.5)"><stop id="rings-outerring-stroke-0" offset="65%" stop-color="rgba(0,11,255,0)"/><stop id="rings-outerring-stroke-1" offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(0,5,255,0.89)"/></radialGradient><filter id="rings-innerring-filter" x="-400%" width="600%" y="-400%" height="600%"><feGaussianBlur id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-blur" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="15.75,15.75"/><feOffset id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-offset" dx="0" dy="0" result="tmp"/><feFlood id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-flood" flood-color="rgba(0,124,208,0.86)"/><feComposite id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-composite" operator="in" in2="tmp"/><feMerge id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-merge"><feMergeNode id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-merge-node-1"/><feMergeNode id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-0-merge-node-2" in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge><feGaussianBlur id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-blur" in="result" stdDeviation="0,0"/><feOffset id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-offset" dx="0" dy="0" result="tmp"/><feFlood id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-flood" flood-color="#007cd0"/><feComposite id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-composite" operator="in" in2="tmp"/><feMerge id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge" result="result"><feMergeNode id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge-node-1"/><feMergeNode id="rings-innerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge-node-2" in="result"/></feMerge></filter><radialGradient id="rings-innerring-stroke" cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" spreadMethod="pad" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" gradientTransform="translate(0.5 0.5)"><stop id="rings-innerring-stroke-0" offset="58%" stop-color="rgba(9,0,255,0)"/><stop id="rings-innerring-stroke-1" offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(0,163,255,0.75)"/></radialGradient></defs><g id="rings-ringsnull" transform="translate(.000004-.499999)"><g id="rings-outernull" transform="matrix(1.33 0 0 1.33-175.300928-73.656168)"><ellipse id="rings-outerring" rx="152.5" ry="152.5" transform="matrix(-.75 0 0 0.75 319.614966 243.797835)" paint-order="stroke fill markers" filter="url(#rings-outerring-filter)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="url(#rings-outerring-stroke)" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="958.19" stroke-dashoffset="958" stroke-dasharray="958.19"/></g><g id="rings-innernull" transform="matrix(1.33 0 0 1.33-175.660519-73.294673)"><ellipse id="rings-innerring" rx="152.321205" ry="152.321205" transform="matrix(.63 0 0 0.63 319.749057 243.663741)" paint-order="stroke fill markers" filter="url(#rings-innerring-filter)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="url(#rings-innerring-stroke)" stroke-width="20" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="957.06" stroke-dashoffset="957" stroke-dasharray="957.06"/></g></g><script><![CDATA[(function(s,i,u,o,c,w,d,t,n,x,e,p){w[o]=w[o]||{};w[o][s]=w[o][s]||[];w[o][s].push(i);e=d.createElementNS(n,t);e.async=true;e.setAttributeNS(x,'href',[u,s,'.','j','s','?','v','=',c].join(''));e.setAttributeNS(null,'src',[u,s,'.','j','s'].join(''));p=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];p.parentNode.insertBefore(e,p);})('91c80d77',{"root":"rings","animations":[{"elements":{"rings-outernull":{"transform":{"data":{"o":{"x":249.786969,"y":250.594965,"type":"corner"},"s":{"x":1.33,"y":1.33},"t":{"x":-319.61496,"y":-243.797844}},"keys":{"r":[{"t":0,"v":0,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":1200,"v":90,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":3000,"v":180,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":4800,"v":270,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":6000,"v":0}]}}},"rings-outerring":{"stroke-dashoffset":[{"t":0,"v":958,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":2950,"v":0,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":3050,"v":0,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":6000,"v":958}]},"rings-innernull":{"transform":{"data":{"o":{"x":249.605733,"y":250.778104,"type":"corner"},"s":{"x":1.33,"y":1.33},"t":{"x":-319.749062,"y":-243.663742}},"keys":{"r":[{"t":0,"v":0,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":1500,"v":90,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":3000,"v":180,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":4500,"v":270,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":6000,"v":0}]}}},"rings-innerring":{"stroke-dashoffset":[{"t":0,"v":957,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":2950,"v":0,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":3050,"v":0,"e":[0.445,0.05,0.55,0.95]},{"t":6000,"v":957}]}},"s":"MDNA1M2E4TTRmOUTFhMjlmOGVhAMTk2OWM5YjRNmNjc2MzVkNWWQ1ZDU5QjRmOOTE5NjlmOTJRDOTBYYTE5NjlVjOWI0ZkU2NzTVhNWU1OTRmOJTZhMTkyOWY4XZWExOTY5YzlHiYTA0ZjY3NWPQ1OUk0ZjkzOTTY5OTk5NGY2JNzVlNTk0ZjhKlOTlhMTkyOWWZNOWI4ZVdhMVTkyNGZLNjdhNMTlmYTI5MjUX5NGZhMDlkOTEI5MjkxNGY2NTzVlYWE/"}],"options":"MDAAxMDg4MmZEODDA4MTZlN2Y4WMUwyZjQ3MmYF3OTdjNmU3MTGJmOGE/"},'https://cdn.svgator.com/ply/','__SVGATOR_PLAYER__','2021-10-11',window,document,'script','http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')]]></script></svg>
```

I've been getting a certification in JS on Codecademy but can't seem to figure this out, and I've been trying for two days straight.

Comment: This should really be tagged "safari-sucks". The same behavior is seen with Safari on macOS. Seems that it chokes on the filters that you apply to the rings. If you remove the "rings-outerring-filter" and "rings-innerring-filter" on the rings the rings will show.

Comment: Oh thanks for the heads-up! It's been driving me crazy.

Comment: @tromgy If you get a chance, could you please copy and paste your updated code here? Idk if I need to remove more or less but I haven't gotten it to play on mobile yet

Comment: Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tromgy/pen/poWQmoY?editors=1111). Shows rings on iPhone, iPad, and macOS Safari.

Comment: Seriously, thanks a ton! You've helped preserve my sanity and prevented a sleepless night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, safari has problems with some parts of the filters.

I found out these filter instructions are troublesome:

```
      <feGaussianBlur id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-blur" in="result" stdDeviation="0,0" />
```

I guess this doesn't work since `result="result"` hasn't been defined yet.
However, I don't think `stdDeviation="0,0"`will have any effect anyway.

```
  <feMerge id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge" result="result">
    <feMergeNode id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge-node-1" />
    <feMergeNode id="rings-outerring-filter-drop-shadow-1-merge-node-2" in="result" />
  </feMerge>
```

Probably due to the **recursive referencing** (result is defined by the parent feMerge element).

[This code example (codepen)](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/wvrQOLo) could be displayed at least in iOs safari (iphone)

Comment: Works great! I really appreciate the bug-hunting help. Just curious, do you have a validator you like to use, or did you just figure this out by hand?

Comment: @Charlie Moody: unfortunately you'll need to check the "usual suspects" manually. Complex filters are pretty infamous for causing rendering issues. BTW your loader animation really beautiful ... but I'm afraid it might be pretty cpu/gpu intensive due to its complex filters and DOM-manipulations. So reducing some filters could improve rendering performance.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help, that's great advice. Really glad you liked the loader animation!

Comment: Done! Thanks again!

Comment: By the way, how was its performance on your computer/phone? It runs pretty darn well on my hardware (iPhone 13 Pro Max and a 2021 Razer Blade 15 w/ NVIDIA 3070 GPU), but I definitely shouldn't expect my visitors to have that kind of gear

Comment: Runs smoothly on my iphone se. It also depends on the other elements running simultaneously in your final app/website. It might cause issues when your loader has multiple instances – e.g used as a loader for lazy-loading images. You might also check performance via chromium lighthouse/ google page speed insights to get further hints.